# How to spell the days of the week in Swiss German?

Tags: pronoun, swiss-german, swiss-standard-german

Came across a timetable that gives some of the days of the week in Swiss German spelling. How to spell the entire week? Please include which dialect you're spelling in in your answer, or provide all variants.

> Mändig, Zyschdig, Mittwuch

Comment: Asking for *spelling* of certain words in  conglomerate of dialects that have no standardized spelling rules is a bit moot. You might get quite a number of spellings from the same region even for the very same word that *sound* entirely the same, but are largely different. Beyond that, it's a asking for a list answer, something that doesn't quite fit into the SE format.

Comment: Dictionaries online: https://www.pauker.at/pauker/DE_DE/SC/wb/ https://www.helvetikon.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different dialects in the swiss german language. But in general the days of the week are pronounced as follows:

- Mäntig
- Zischtig
- Mittwuch
- Donnschtig
- Fritig
- Samschtig
- Sonntig

But if you take the valais dialect (one of the most special), for example, you say for monday "Meentagg".

Comment: Why did you reply "Mäntig, Zischtig, Mittwuch" when the question itself shows different spellings: "Mändig, Zyschdig, Mittwuch" without any explanation about the difference?

Comment: Why *"There are different dialects…."*, and it would go beyond the scope to write down the days of the week in every swiss dialect.